# Is it possible to alias Glassfish requests like in Apache?

Tags: apache, glassfish, cgi

I want to redirect requests to `/program.fcgi?` to the actual location on the filesystem which is `/usr/local/.../program.fcgi?`.  In Apache I can add the following to the configuration file

```
Alias /program /usr/local/.../program
```

How do I do the same in Glassfish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glassfish lets you include a `sun-web.xml` in `WEB-INF` of your web application that allows you to provide alternate docroots

An example entry would look like :

`<property name="alternatedocroot_1" value="from=*.jsp dir=path_to_directory"/>`

Details [here](http://wikis.sun.com/display/GlassFish/FaqAlternateDocrootResourcePath)

Comment: That link has moved to https://wikis.oracle.com/display/GlassFish/FaqAlternateDocrootResourcePath